# Applying Riemann-Roch to a rank 2 vector bundle on a complex surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex surface, $F$ a rank 2 vector bundle on $X$, $n$ a positive integer, $S^nF$ the $n$-th symmetric product of $F$, $P$ a rational divisor, and $a$ a rational number such that $naP$ is integral. Suppose $\det(F)=P+N$ with $P\cdot N=0$, $P$ nef, and $N$ effective. Also suppose $h^0(S^nF(-naP))$ and $h^2(S^nF(-naP))$ are both $O(n^2)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).
In the proof of Proposition 2.2 of this paper (link: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1272710), there is the following statement:

Riemann-Roch gives $\chi(S^nF(-naP))=\dfrac{n^3}{6}\{ (1-3a+3a^2)P^2+N^2-c_2(F) \}+O(n^2)$

But how does the Riemann-Roch theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem imply the equality?

Comment: This is Riemann-Roch for a vector bundle on a surface; probably one just needs the generality of Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch rather than a more explicit statement.

Comment: Per Tabes Bridges' comment, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem_for_surfaces) is the Riemann-Roch theorem you want.